# Send JSON data to ASP.NET HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax, httphandler

Am trying to send JSON data to HTTP handler through ajax am unable to retrieve JSON data at Handler

Here is my code to send json data

function SendJsonData() {

```
        var Jsonstring = "[{ AssetName: 'ANA001', AssetNumber: 'ANU001',SerialNumber:'S001',RFIDTag:'R001'},{ AssetName: 'ANA002', AssetNumber: 'ANU002',SerialNumber:'S002',RFIDTag:'R002'},{ AssetName: 'ANA003', AssetNumber: 'ANU003',SerialNumber:'S003',RFIDTag:'R003'}]";

        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(Jsonstring);
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: myJSON ,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:58275/NFCDataHandlerData.ashx",
            //  url: "http://166.78.189.76:93/NFCDataHandlerData.ashx",                
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my handle code which i tried like these methods but am not getting JSON data

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        //var data = context.Request;
        //var sr = new StreamReader(data.InputStream);
        //var stream = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //          var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        //var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(stream);

        //string objectdata = jsonObject.ToString();
        //string Jsondata = string.Empty;

        //if (HttpContext.Current.Request["Jsondata"] != null)
        //{
        //    Jsondata = HttpContext.Current.Request["Jsondata"];
        //}

        string json1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["json"];

        string objectdata = string.Empty;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request["Jsonstring"] != null)
        {
            objectdata = HttpContext.Current.Request["Jsonstring"];
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<NFCAssetData> myObjs = new List<NFCAssetData>();
        myObjs = json.Deserialize<List<NFCAssetData>>(objectdata);
```

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepare valid data

```
// either from object
var myJSON = JSON.stringify([{ AssetName: 'ANA001', AssetNumber: 'ANU001'}])
// or from valid JSON string
var myJSON = '[{"AssetName":"ANA001","AssetNumber":"ANU001"}]'
```

What you have now is JSON-encoded string with invalid JSON.

And server-side should look like this

```
var request = context.Request;
var requestBody = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<NFCAssetData>>(requestBody);
```